# How do I pass multiple JSON from servlet to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, servlets

I want to pass 3 JSON to front end. I can pass all 3 individually. I did this to check if its working.

I do it this way:

```
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

I read on one of the post on here that you could put the create a json array and send the array to the Ajax call.

So I tried doing this:

```
String json = "["+ json1.toString() + "," + json2.toString() + "," + json3.toString() + "]"; 
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

In the client side of the house:

```
$.ajax({
        data: {param1: 'p1', param2: 'p2', param3: 'p3', param4: 'p'},
        dataType: 'json',
        url: './GetDataServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            var   data1 = data[0];
            var   data2 = data[1]; 
            var   data3 = data[2];
$.each(data1 , function(i, val) {
 $("#personal_data").append("<p> val.firstname </p>")
 $("#personal_data").append("<p> val.lastname </p>")
)};
$.each(data2 , function(i, val) {
 $("#department_data").append("<p> val.departmentid </p>")
 $("#demartment_data").append("<p> val.departmentname </p>")
)};

//Not attaching the entire code, because it's quite long. :) 
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occured while attempting fetch data.");
        }
    });
```

How can you pass multiple JSONs to the client side when you make an $.ajax call.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not make three different calls or return a collection /array of three json objects ?

Comment: What you are doing there is ordering a triple JSON sandwich. What you want to do is order three JSON sandwiches. Your server will know what order to eat the three individual JSON sandwiches in, because it knows the order in which you ordered them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending a single array of the three objects. `[Obj1 , Obj2 , Obj3]`

If the three objects returned depend on the previous objects sent (say `Obj2` depends on `Obj1.X` property is true or false you can have three separate calls

```
var firstResult = $.ajax({  
    url : firstUrl  
    ... other details
});

var firstResult.done(function(Obj1){

  if(Obj1.X){
    $.ajax({  
      url : secondUrl  
      ... other details
    });

   ... other calls
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In properly formed JSON and AJAX requests/responses, 1 call delivers 1 JSON string.

Of course, you can compose those JSON strings however you want within the allowable JSON structure.  In your case, there is absolutely nothing wrong with composing three JSON objects within a JSON array wrapper.

I think perhaps your only issue is here:

```
String json = "["+ json1.toString() + "," + json2.toString() + "," + json3.toString() + "]"; 
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

The String `json` that you build is already a string, so you don't need to call `toString()` on it again.  Just do:

```
String json = "["+ json1.toString() + "," + json2.toString() + "," + json3.toString() + "]"; 
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Comment: I added the toString() intentionally because I got this error: GET http://localhost:8080/DataDictionary-v1.1.2/css/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png 404 (Not Found) (Javascript console). When I put the toString() it doesn't happen. Not sure why.

Comment: Not sure what writing a JSON response would have to do with a 404 error on some CSS image file.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing. I wanted to pass three json objects to my javascript. I tried making the three json objects into one json array and passing it,but it complicated the situation greatly.

I found that passing a string separated by a character I chose "%" is much easier.

```
    String json1 = "....";
    String json2 = "....";
    String json3 = "...";
    String toApp = json1 + "%" + json2 + "%" + json3;
```

Then in javascript you can split the text with

```
var split = line.split("%");
```

Finally a json object can be made from split[0], split[1] and split [2].

Answer (score 0):

```
 var c1= new Object();
c1.property1="test";
c1.property2="test";

var c2= new Object();
c2.property1="test";
c2.property2="test";

var data = { 'c1': c1, 'c2': c2 };
var parameters1 = JSON.stringify(data);

In ajax call pass parameters1 as data.
  [WebMethod]
  public static bool TestMethod(Object c1, Object c2)
  {
  }
```